# Исключить дублирование select

Tags: oracle

Есть таблица:
**prov_dl**

```
| ID | Code     | Value |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | PRC      | 0,1701|
| 2  | Stad     | 3     |
```

Данные хранятся в таком виде то есть по коду есть несколько записей
Нужно вытащить данные в таком виде:

```
  | ID | Stadya   | Percent   |
  +----+----------+-----------+
  | 2  | 3        | 0,1701    |
```

Пробую так:

```
select id,
case when code='Stad' then Value  end Stadya,
case when code='PRC'  then  Value end Percent  
from prov_dl   

| ID | Stadya   | Percent|
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  |          | 0,1701 |
| 2  |   3      |        |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id,
    max(case when code='Stad' then Value  end) as Stadya,
    max(case when code='PRC'  then  Value end) as Percent  
    from prov_dl group by id
```

Comment: Стандартный прием, называется "разворот CASE'ом"

Comment: Если нужно вытягивать большое количество параметров, то удобнее использовать PIVOT https://oracleplsql.ru/pivot.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value Stadya, t2.value Percent
FROM prov_dl t1
JOIN prov_dl t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.code='Stad'
  AND t2.code='PRC'
```

Предполагается, что на `(id, code)` имеет место быть уникальный индекс.

Будут выведены записи только для тех ID, для которых имеется оба типа значений.

Answer (score 1):

будут id без повторения при условии что поля не пустые

```
SELECT distinct(t1.id), t1.value stadya, t2.value percent
FROM prov_dl t1
JOIN prov_dl t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
where t1.value <> null and t2.value <> null
```

А так вариант от Zhandos очень даже и не плох.